# grep -f return only first match (of many)

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

Trying to get a bit more out of the command line:

I have a file:

```
CHR25   1192279 Y       Exonic  NA      exon    2       [1/1]   1192145 1192322
CHR25   1192279 Y       Exonic  NA      CDS     2       [1/1]   1192145 1192322  
CHR25   1739394 Y       Exonic  NA      CDS     2       [1/2]   1739294 1739456
```

I want to get unique lines based on column 2. I have done

```
cat file | cut -f 2 | uniq > grepfile
```

but am unsure of how to now get one match per line using `grep -f` as I previously have. Using `-m1 or | head -n 1` only gives the first matching line. I want the first line to match each line in 'grepfile'.

Look forward to answers=)

Comment: So you'd just want the first and third lines in the example? Or second and third? does it matter which?

Comment: It is not clear from the question what you want to achieve. Add the final output that you want to get based on the sample input file that you have already provided and I'm sure we will be able to help.

Comment: I think I got it. It's a job for awk. `awk '!s[$2]++'`

Comment: I just want to get the first match for each of the lines in `grepfile`

Comment: @AlanCurry that works nicely, really need to get to know awk

Comment: Won't solve your problem, but you don't need `cat` at the start .. `cut -f 2 file | ...` will work

Comment: @AlanCurry You should make it an answer so that user1495853 can accept it

Comment: how does `grep` fit in to this? What are you trying to do? Note: `uniq` does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent. You may want to sort the input first, or use `sort -u` without `uniq`

Comment: If preserving order is unimportant then sort can do the whole thing. `sort -u +1 -2` (traditional) or `sort -u -k2,2` (POSIX)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This awk command works by building an associative array of second-field values that have been seen already.

```
awk '!s[$2]++'
```

The associative array is called `s`. The expression looks up $2 (the second column of the input line) and applies a postincrement, which will return 0 the first time it's called and nonzero thereafter. Then I invert it, yield 1 the first time each $2 is seen, and 0 every time afterward. And awk's default action is to print if the selecting expression is true.

Just watch out when the line count is big enough to wrap around to 0 again.

Comment: +1 for `awk` .. it should be noted that if you use the `csh/tcsh` you'll need to escape the `!`, so `awk '\!s[$2]++'` will work.

Comment: +1 Great solution, but what about spending a few characters more to make the explanation redundant and to avoid the overflow? `awk 's[$2]==0 { s[$2]=1; print }'`

Answer (score 2):

This will work too:

```
sort -u  -k2,2 file
```

giving:

```
CHR25   1192279 Y       Exonic  NA      exon    2       [1/1]   1192145 1192322
CHR25   1739394 Y       Exonic  NA      CDS     2       [1/2]   1739294 1739456
```

`-u` invokes `uniq`, `-k2,2` means sort on field 2 (and only field 2) as can be seen on the sort [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort).

Comment: -u and --unique mean unique, like uniq. But the uniq command is not invoked.

Comment: @richard right you are .. thanks for pointing this out. I should have looked more carefully at the man page, I just saw uniq* :)

Comment: @user1495853 You are welcome. If any of these solutions on this page helped feel free to upvote them. And consider picking your favorite and [*accept it by clicking on the checkmark*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) next to the answer. That'll reward both parties with some rep points and mark this problem as solved.

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is okay, you can do:

```
perl -nale '$h{$F[1]}=$_ if(!$h{$F[1]});END{print $h{$_}for(keys(%h));}' file
```

Comment: I could do it in Perl (with many more lines) but am trying to use command line. Thanks though.

Comment: I could do it in perl almost the same way I did in awk: `perl -nae 'print if !$s{$F[1]}++'`

Answer (score 0):

Because uniq only looks at adjacent lines, and sort changes the order. You need a bit more code.

```
cat -n input-file | sort --key=3,3 --unique | sort | cut -f2- >output-file
```

1. `cat -n` to add sequence numbers.
2. `sort --key=3,3 --unique` to remove duplicates on field 2. note: key number is one higher, because of `cat -n`.
3. `sort` to put back in original order.
4. `cut -f2-` to get rig of the sequence numbers.